# Probability of more that half of events happening

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $n$ independent events each of them having $p_i$ probability of happening. What is most elegant way to find a probability of at least half of the events happening? I can see only ugly combinatorial approach...

Comment: and each $p_i$ could be different from one another?  Yuck...  If all $p_i$ are the same, this could be described easily as a binomial distribution.

Comment: @JMoravitz yep, this is exactly the problem.

Comment: I would advice to read the wikipedia page of the multinomial distribution, this is a generalization of the binomial distribution.

Comment: You have the expected proportion of events being $\frac1n \sum p_i$ with variance  $\frac1n \sum p_i(1-p_i)$ so for large $n$ and $p_i$s not too close to $0$ or $1$ you might be able to use the Central Limit Theorem approximation